# QT Exception treatment

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, exception, warnings

I've been trying to make a list in Qt that adds and removes integers for my Data Structures class, the teacher asked for a GUI, but I've been struggling a bit with the exception. I have managed to show the error when the list is empty, but the program closes after that, I wanted it to keep running after the warning popup window, but i have no idea how to proceed. I'm using try and catch to do that. Here is one of my remove buttons, this one removes the first int of the list.

```
    void MainWindow::on_removerInicio_clicked()
    {
        try
        {
            throw ListaSeq.isEmpty();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            QMessageBox::warning(this,tr("Aviso!"),tr("Lista Vazia!"));
        }

        ui->listWidget->takeItem(0);
        ListaSeq.removeFirst();
        nElementos--;
        ui->nElementos->setText(QString::number(nElementos));
    }
```

I know it's wrong but I don't know how to fix it, when clicked it shows the warning, but also closes the program. Can you help me?

Edit: Also if i take out the code

```
        ui->listWidget->takeItem(0);
        ListaSeq.removeFirst();
        nElementos--;
        ui->nElementos->setText(QString::number(nElementos));
```

The programs works fine and return to the mainwindow.

Comment: Can't see a problem with the try/catch.  Can you try changing the try/catch into a simple `if` test.  If the program still exits then the issue is elsewhere

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger to see where the program is exiting?

Comment: The if test just breaks the program. Or maybe i did it wrong. I tried.
if(ListaSeq.isEmpty())
{
QMessageBox::warning(this,tr("Aviso!"),tr("Lista Vazia!"));
}

Comment: Debugger showed me this
        ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file C:\Qt\5.10.0\mingw53_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 351

Comment: After you close the warning this line: `ListaSeq.removeFirst();` will fail as the list is empty.  Put the code after the warning in the `else` part of the `if` test.

Comment: Oh wow, how did i forget that lol, thank you!